# A simple C# program giving unhandled exception after execution

Tags: c#

https://i.stack.imgur.com/smnXF.png

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fname, mname, sname, Desig, input, option1, option2;
            int EmpID;
            option1 = ".value";
            option2 = ".ini";



            Console.WriteLine("Enter Employ ID: \t");                           // Data input start                                                                                                                                                              
            EmpID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter First Name: \t");
            fname = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Middle Name: \t");
            mname = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Surame: \t");
            sname = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Designation: \t");                       //data input end
            Desig = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n Choose from the following options:-");                     //options
            Console.WriteLine("\n type .value to show all details of the employees");
            Console.WriteLine("\n type .ini to show all the initials of the employe name");


            input = Console.ReadLine();


            if (String.Equals(input, option1) || String.Equals(input, option2))                 //conditional begin

            {

                 if(string.Equals(input,option1))                                                //sub-conditional begin
            {              
               Console.WriteLine("\n\nName of the employee={1} {2} {3} , His Employee ID ={3} And His Designation is as {4} ",fname[0],mname[0],sname[0],Desig[0]);
            }


            else
            {            
                Console.WriteLine("{1}{2}{3}", fname.Substring(0,1), mname.Substring(0,1), sname.Substring(0,1));
            }
                                                                  //sub-conditional ends

            else
            {            
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease Enter a valid input...");    
            }                                                                                   //conditional ends

        }

    }

}
```

Simple program , takes input data , then input option , checks the option and runs the desired block using if/else conditionals.

PS: I know switch is a more nobler option , but I want to know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exception exactly? On which line? What is your inputs? You need to be more specific when you ask. By the way please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times..

Comment: added the image to the error on top. why are guys downvoting this?

Comment: dont put this on hold. this is a genuine question. I am very confused by this occurrence.I added the pic . I dont have anyone who can help me out where i live , so I need some help. Or dont help. wtv. dgaf

Answer (score 2):

That code should give `FormatException`. Indexes in format strings are zero-based, yours starts from 1. Fix it in every `Console.WriteLine` call like that:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", fname[0], mname[0], sname[0]);
```

Comment: did it,no change. look at the edits in the code. ' .ini ' goves the initials of the whole name

Comment: Are you sure you fixed all `Console.WriteLine` calls like I suggested? Specially checked, everything else is fine - except one `}` is missing before final `else`, which probably is a copy-paste typo, and there's no `Console.ReadLine()` in the end to see the output.

Comment: yeah. i did all that you said,and more. still the same error(see the pic on top) . PS:there are no errors  shown in the IDE , just after it has been compile and run,in the console